# Google Sheets, Conditional Formatting, Check each cell if the cell "next to it" has the same value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

thanks in advance for looking at my question.

So what I'm trying to do, is to check whether cells in columns "C" and "E" have matching values(Only comparing every row on its own).

If they have matching values they should be highlighted in red.

In below Image you can see what I've tried so far.(I tried making column C cells red if they match column E cells.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do it with [=EXACT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094073?hl=en)

Sample:

`=EXACT(C1,E1)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've tried "EXACT" but the problem is, I'd have to do it about 140 times :/

Comment: If you specify the range as you did before, the formula `=EXACT(C1,E1)` will applied to the whole specified range and not only row 1.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I don't know why it works though, but you solved my problem! Thank you very much!